# Set lookup property on Navigation Property failing

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I am trying to `POST` the below json using the Microsoft Dynamics WebAPI.  The post returns a success, but in my data the ccseq_employeeid and ccseq_clientid are not set.  What do I need to change to get the fields to post correctly?

### Entity Structure

`ccseq_expensetransaction` has a lookup to `ccseq_expensetransactionsets` with a relationship that has the name `ccseq_ccseq_expensetransactionset_ccseq_expensetransaction_ExpenseTransactionSetID`.  The lookups to `systemusers` and `ccseq_clients` are a part of the `ccseq_expensetransaction` entity.

### Code

```
POST /api/data/v8.0/ccseq_expensetransactionsets HTTP/1.1
Host: url.com
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 24f7ead3-0307-996f-f45a-f959c604c922

{
   "ccseq_importdate":"2017-06-05T04:00:00Z",
   "ccseq_month":"1",
   "ccseq_year":"2017",
   "ccseq_name":"Test 30",
   "ccseq_status":"100000000",
   "ccseq_ccseq_expensetransactionset_ccseq_expensetransaction_ExpenseTransactionSetID":[
      {
         "ExpenseTransaction[ccseq_employeeid@odata.bind]":"/systemusers(6d2fd71b-32d1-dd11-a4f5-001a6449bbe7)",
         "ExpenseTransaction[ccseq_clientid@odata.bind]":"/ccseq_clients(663ebd00-73b9-4faf-90ed-f56bb9c2dc9b)"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the body of the request into this:

```
{
   "ccseq_importdate": "2017-06-05T04:00:00Z",
   "ccseq_month": "1",
   "ccseq_year": "2017",
   "ccseq_name": "Test 30",
   "ccseq_status": "100000000",
   "ccseq_employeeid@odata.bind": "/systemusers(6d2fd71b-32d1-dd11-a4f5-001a6449bbe7)",
   "ccseq_clientid@odata.bind": "/ccseq_clients(663ebd00-73b9-4faf-90ed-f56bb9c2dc9b)"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I believe it's because the `systemusers` and `ccseq_clients` lookups are on the child entity `ccseq_expensetransaction`.  See my updated question for the details of my entity structure.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to update fields on related entities in one and the same request.